# Проблема с множественным вызовом OpenGL-функции render() в QtQuick

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

Рисую текстуру на OpenGL через FrameBufferObject в QtQuick окно.

Инициализация:

```
FbItemRenderer::FbItemRenderer(const FbItem *item)
{
    m_item = item;

    texture = new QOpenGLTexture(QImage(":/coolimage.png").mirrored());
    texture->setMinificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::LinearMipMapLinear);
    texture->setMagnificationFilter(QOpenGLTexture::Linear);

    glViewport(0, 0, 800, 600);
    glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);
    glLoadIdentity();
    glOrtho(0, 800, 600, 0, 1, 0);
    glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
}
```

Рендер:

```
void FbItemRenderer::render()
{
    glClearColor ( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
    glClear      ( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

    glEnable ( GL_BLEND );
    glBlendFunc ( GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
    glEnable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D );

    GLfloat vertices[] = { i,i,
                           texture->width()+i,i,
                           texture->width()+i,texture->height()+i,
                           i,texture->height()+i
                         };
    GLfloat texVertices[] = { 0,0, 1,0, 1,1, 0,1 };

    glEnableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
    glEnableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT);

    texture->bind();
    glVertexPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, vertices);
    glTexCoordPointer(2, GL_FLOAT, 0, texVertices);
    glDrawArrays(GL_QUADS, 0, 4);

    glDisableClientState(GL_TEXTURE_COORD_ARRAY_EXT);
    glDisableClientState(GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);

    glDisable ( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
    glDisable ( GL_BLEND );

    //i++;
    m_item->window()->resetOpenGLState();
    //update();
}
```

Вот так текстура рисуется как положено. Но когда я добавляю в конец функции render() функцию update(), текстура пропадает после вызова update(). Т.е. она рисуется только в первой итерации. Уже все перепробовал, может что-то еще нужно добавить?

**upd** Обнаружил, что текстура рисуется на первых *двух* прогонах функции render()

**upd** Тут же и обнаруживается странное поведение: при циклическом инкременте переменной i текстура перемещается только на третьем(!) цикле, несмотря на то, что значения вершин изменились. Точнее, на третьем цикле перемещается не текстура, а квадрат, в котором должна быть текстура.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема решена при помощи примера от Qt http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtquick-scenegraph-textureinsgnode-example.html на основе которого я изначально и пытался рисовать.

Поместил код отрисовки текстуры в этот пример и нашел недостающие детали головоломки. Оказалось необходимо добавить шейдеры. Достаточно просто пустых шейдеров.

Объявляем в классе:

```
QOpenGLShaderProgram program1;
```

Добавляем в функцию инициализации:

```
QOpenGLShader *vshader1 = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Vertex, &program1);
    const char *vsrc1 =
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "}\n";
    vshader1->compileSourceCode(vsrc1);

    QOpenGLShader *fshader1 = new QOpenGLShader(QOpenGLShader::Fragment, &program1);
    const char *fsrc1 =
        "void main(void)\n"
        "{\n"
        "}\n";
    fshader1->compileSourceCode(fsrc1);

    program1.addShader(vshader1);
    program1.addShader(fshader1);

    //program1.link();
```

И в функции render() до отрисовки картинки добавляем:

```
//glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
//program1.bind();
//program1.setUniformValue(matrixUniform1, modelview);
program1.release();
glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
```

Фишка еще в том, что закоменченные строки разкомменчивать необязательно, если шейдеры использовать не планируется.